# Rounding numbers while supporting negative values

Tags: javascript, numbers, rounding

I need to round a number up to two digits (**NOTE**: that I need a solution that support positive AND negative numbers) I'm currently using `toFixed(2)` but that doesn't round it, I've Googled / Stack Overflow'ed but couldn't really find an answer for my situation:

```
const value = -0.004;
console.log(value.toFixed(2)); // 0.00
// Expected: -0.01
```

Anyone a clue? Keep safe.

Comment: For 2 decimal digits, multiply by 100, then use `Math.ceil` or `Math.floor` depending on whether you want to round up or down, then divide by 100 again. If you run into floating-point issues, you can call `toFixed(2)` on it after that

Comment: can try this link similar question
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11832950/9977272